# turtle.xcor() working for certain turtle objects, not others

Tags: python

So, i'm fairly new to python, and i'm using turtle. I want to make a basic game where you simply have the character go from one side to the other using x coordinates ( y coordinates do not matter as there are walls to stop you from going up to a point where you pass the goal and still win ), my code is basically that if you pass the xcor() of the objective, it pops up a message saying "you won", i got the coordinate collision system working for the walls, but it doesnt work for the objective.

```
import turtle as Turtle

Window = Turtle.Screen()
Window.title("Game")
Window.bgcolor("grey")
Window.setup(width=800, height=600)
Window.tracer(0)

Instructions = Turtle.Turtle()
Instructions.speed(0)
Instructions.color("black")
Instructions.penup()
Instructions.hideturtle()
Instructions.goto(100,300)
Instructions.write("Get to the Objective, do not touch the walls.", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

Player = Turtle.Turtle()
Player.speed(0)
Player.shape("square")
Player.color("black", "white")
Player.penup()
Player.goto(0, 0)
Player.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)

Objective = Turtle.Turtle()
Objective.speed(0)
Objective.shape("square")
Objective.color("black", "lightgreen")
Objective.penup()
Objective.goto(900, 0)
Objective.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=5)

Obstacle = Turtle.Turtle()
Obstacle.speed(0)
Obstacle.shape("square")
Obstacle.color("black", "darkgrey")
Obstacle.penup()
Obstacle.goto(450, -120)
Obstacle.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=50)

Obstacle2 = Turtle.Turtle()
Obstacle2.speed(0)
Obstacle2.shape("square")
Obstacle2.color("black", "darkgrey")
Obstacle2.penup()
Obstacle2.goto(450, 120)
Obstacle2.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=50)

Obstacle3 = Turtle.Turtle()
Obstacle3.speed(0)
Obstacle3.shape("square")
Obstacle3.color("black", "darkgrey")
Obstacle3.penup()
Obstacle3.goto(-80, 0)
Obstacle3.shapesize(stretch_wid=14, stretch_len=2,)

Obstacle4 = Turtle.Turtle()
Obstacle4.speed(0)
Obstacle4.shape("square")
Obstacle4.color("black", "darkgrey")
Obstacle4.penup()
Obstacle4.goto(980, 0)
Obstacle4.shapesize(stretch_wid=14, stretch_len=2,)


def PlayerForward():
    if Player.ycor() > -40 and Player.ycor() < 40 and Player.xcor() > -1:
        Player.forward(10)
    else:
        Turtle.setpos(0, -180)
        Turtle.write("you touched the wall", font="arial")
        Turtle.hideturtle()


def PlayerBackward():
    if Player.ycor() > -40 and Player.ycor() < 40 and Player.xcor() > -1:
        Player.backward(10)
    else:
        Turtle.setpos(0, -180)
        Turtle.write("you touched the wall", font="arial")
        Turtle.hideturtle()


def PlayerRight():
    if Player.ycor() > -40 and Player.ycor() < 40 and Player.xcor() > -1:
        Player.right(10)
    else:
        Turtle.setpos(0, -180)
        Turtle.write("you touched the wall", font="arial")
        Turtle.hideturtle()


def PlayerLeft():
    if Player.ycor() > -40 and Player.ycor() < 40 and Player.xcor() > -1:
        Player.left(10)
    else:
        Turtle.setpos(0, -180)
        Turtle.write("you touched the wall", font="arial")
        Turtle.hideturtle()

#this is the part that doesn't work, I've tried if player.xcor() > 800 ( around where it should touch Objective, haven't got the coordinates down exact as even if you went out of bounds way beyond the coords, it still wont work as this never worked either )
if Player.distance(Objective) < 10:
    Turtle.write("You got to the objective, congrats.", font="arial")
    Turtle.hideturtle()


Turtle.listen()
Turtle.onkeypress(PlayerForward, "w")
Turtle.onkeypress(PlayerBackward, "s")
Turtle.onkeypress(PlayerRight, "d")
Turtle.onkeypress(PlayerLeft, "a")

while True:
    Window.update()
```

Comment: Your `if` statement only executes once, at the start of your program. Try moving it within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the code to check if the objective has been reached every time a move is made.

To do that create a new function, let's call it checkObjective.

```
def checkObjective():
  if Player.distance(Objective) < 10:
    Turtle.write("You got to the objective, congrats.", font="arial")
    Turtle.hideturtle()
```

Now call it every time a move is made, for example when moving forward.

```
def PlayerForward():
    if Player.ycor() > -40 and Player.ycor() < 40 and Player.xcor() > -1:
        Player.forward(10)
        checkObjective()
    else:
        Turtle.setpos(0, -180)
        Turtle.write("you touched the wall", font="arial")
        Turtle.hideturtle()
```